# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'enable_eager_execution'

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, anaconda, tensorflow2.0

I just tried to enable eager execution in my shell which is actually showing an error:

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'enable_eager_execution'
```

My Tensorflow version is 2.0

[image: The image shows my tensorflow version]

can anyone tell me why am I getting this...

Thanks in advance

Comment: You don't need to activate eager in TF 2.0, it's activated by default.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`Tensorflow 2.0` has eager_execution enabled by default and so there is no need for you to run `tf.enable_eager_execution`. Only if your running versions below `2.0` should you enable eager execution

Answer (score 6):

Eager execution is enabled by default in version 2.x
You can check that by using

```
tf.executing_eagerly()
```

It should return True. If you are having version less then 2.0 then it can be enabled by using

```
tf.enable_eager_execution()
```

Answer (score 3):

for tensorflow v1.x code, this will works:

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_v2_behavior()
tf.enable_eager_execution()
```

Answer (score 2):

Eager enabled by default in tf2, you do can disable it as below

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
```

If you do have to call something, **tf.compat.v1.enable_eager_execution** is available.

Answer (score 1):

I got same error and many with version 2.0. Downgrading to 1.1X is not the solution.

Follow the instruction at 
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/35749

Install latest visual C++. reboot your machine . It should work
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads

Comment: Tensorflow 2.1.0 is compiled using MSVC 2019, which appears to require an additional DLL. As per https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/36167

Answer (score -1):

Eager execution mode was added to Tensorflow starting with version 1.8. So an update is necessary. In addition, it is a relatively new feature with many glitches and frequent updates, so using the most recent version that can work for you is recommended. Try

```
conda update tensorflow
```

or with pip

```
pip install --upgrade Tensorflow
```

Answer (score -1):

I have Keras v2.1.0 installed. Eager_execution was not enabled by default and 
`import tensorflow.contrib.eager as tfe
tfe.enable_eager_execution()`

did **not** work for me. (A check using `tf.executing_eagerly()` returned *False*.)

**However,** what worked for me was:

`import tensorflow as tf
tf.enable_eager_execution()`

**Note:** tf.placeholder() is not compatible with eager execution.